# What is the reason behind Guest Cart Clean in Hybris OOTB Guest Checkout implementation in DefaultGuestCheckoutCartCleanStrategy?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

What is the reason behind the logic of the OOTB DefaultGuestCheckoutCartCleanStrategy.cleanGuestCart(). 
Why is that needed to delete all the cart data after the guest user leaves the checkout for eg. to visit the choosen product again?

Answer (score -1):

Hybris not clean cart items OOTB while guest using site. It is only removing payment methods and address. May be in your system, guest lost their session while leaving cart. On the other hand there is existing cron job for cleaning abandoned carts. May be it is configured as 0 for cart age.

Comment: Regarding the following documentation, Hybris does clean the cart in the OOTB guest checkout: https://help.sap.com/viewer/4c33bf189ab9409e84e589295c36d96e/1905/en-US/8adb50aa866910149533e8c748b730c9.html?q=guest%20checkout

Comment: I mention below about cron job. Also your help link has same information as "Removing address and payment data for abandoned checkouts is done using cron jobs.". Check your guest cart in db level. If it is not exist check your cron job.

Comment: That cronjob is well known to me, thx. I was pionting out the AnonymousCheckoutFilter, which (as the documentation states too) removes any information if the user leaves the checkout. This is the part my question is about. Also note that this filter does call the cleanGuestCart function which I was refering as well.

Comment: Given cleanGuestCart function only remove payment and address. It is not delete items. If you create your own strategy, check it. Otherwise may be you can change guest GUID on PDP page. That function update customer as current guest user user on cart.